# R Convert data frame to matrix keeping certain columns as numeric

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have the following data fame df:

```
  author         filename    a   all  also
1  dispt dispt_fed_49.txt 0.28 0.052 0.009
2  dispt dispt_fed_50.txt 0.18 0.063 0.013
3  dispt dispt_fed_51.txt 0.34 0.090 0.008
4  dispt dispt_fed_52.txt 0.27 0.024 0.016
5  dispt dispt_fed_53.txt 0.30 0.054 0.027
```

I want to convert to matrix using:

```
mat <- as.matrix(df)
```

But the result shows numeric columns as text:

```
 author           filename              a       all     also   
 [1,] "dispt"    "dispt_fed_49.txt"    "0.280" "0.052" "0.009"
 [2,] "dispt"    "dispt_fed_50.txt"    "0.177" "0.063" "0.013"
 [3,] "dispt"    "dispt_fed_51.txt"    "0.339" "0.090" "0.008"
 [4,] "dispt"    "dispt_fed_52.txt"    "0.270" "0.024" "0.016"
 [5,] "dispt"    "dispt_fed_53.txt"    "0.303" "0.054" "0.027"
```

How can I keep these as numeric while

Comment: You can't. A `matrix` contains only one class of data at a time. You want to continue using a `data.frame` instead.

Comment: What is your reasoning for wanting to transform it to a `matrix`? Perhaps what you think is the problem (requiring a `matrix` as the solution) can be addressed a different way.

Comment: I'm trying to do clustering using hclust(distMatrix,method="ward.D")  but in order to calculate distMatrix I need my dataframe as matrix. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Sigmarabi1 - subset the numeric part out and it should be good to go - `as.matrix(df[c("a","all","also")])`

Comment: Voting to close. Requests to make matrices in R hold diverse types of elements is just impossible.